# Keras: Get a single batch from a custom generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I created a custom generator using the code here https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3386#issuecomment-237555199 as a template. Instead of using `.flow` I want to use `.flow_from_dataframe`. As such my generator looks like this:

```
def createGenerator( X, I):

    while True:

        # suffled indices    
        idx = np.random.permutation( X.shape[0])
        # create image generator
        datagen=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
                              horizontal_flip = True,
                              rotation_range=20)


        batches = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(shuffle=False,dataframe=X[["url",target]], directory=bilder_resized_dir, x_col="url", y_col=target,
                                            has_ext=False, class_mode="categorical", color_mode=color_mode, target_size=(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE), batch_size=batch_size,classes=class_list)
        idx0 = 0
        for batch in batches:
            idx1 = idx0 + batch[0].shape[0]

            yield [batch[0], I[ idx[ idx0:idx1 ] ]], batch[1]

            idx0 = idx1
            if idx1 >= X.shape[0]:
                break
```

Now I would like to test this generator by inspecting the output of a single batch. I tried using `next()` like so:

```
combo_gen = createGenerator(X1_dataframe ,X2_aux_input)
x,y = next(combo_gen)
```

However this gives me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-274-4a67da5d38d9> in <module>
----> 1 x,y = next(combo_gen)

StopIteration:
```

**Question:**

How can I get a single batch from this generator?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `__getitem__` method of the custom generator, e.g. with the index =0 to get the first batch.